# sqlite android extract contacts with phone number

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contacts

I'm facing this sqlite issue in which I'm trying to extract the contacts that have phone number/s with the following query:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
    query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI
            },
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + ">?",
            new String [] {"0"},
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"
    );
```

The problem is that in the case that the contact has more than 1 phone number the result will be in this form:

```
id: 451, name: Maria, photoUri: null, has_phone_number: 1, phone_number: 0700 000 000
id: 451, name: Maria, photoUri: null, has_phone_number: 1, phone_number: 0800 000 000
id: 451, name: Maria, photoUri: null, has_phone_number: 1, phone_number: 0900 000 000
```

which is undesirable because of the duplicate data.

I want to make **only 1 query** to the db that hopefully can be written to return the result like this:

```
id: 451, name: Maria, photoUri: null, has_phone_number: 1, phone_number: 0700 000 000, 0800 000 000, 0900 000 000
```

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: i dont think its possible the way android db is setup. is it out of the question to put this into a list and merge them manually with a loop or something? i know that prob isnt a good way but i cant think of a better one.

Comment: It needs to work with contacts in the range of thousands, I would want to avoid doing extra processing.

Comment: I don't know android, but this isn't too difficult to do in SQL. Can you run raw SQL queries against your database though, or are you restricted to using that query function?

Comment: I am restricted to use that method or any other that takes as parameter an Uri: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, bc this will query the phone's db. I can not use a raw query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible what you want to do, This is a workaround using a HashMap. It can handle thousands of entries, so don't worry.

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI },
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + ">?",
            new String [] {"0"},
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    Map<String, List<String>> phonesPerContact = new HashMap<>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(2);
            String phone = cursor.getString(1);

            if (!phonesPerContact.containsKey(name)){
                phonesPerContact.put(name, new ArrayList<String>());
            }

            phonesPerContact.get(name).add(phone);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    for (String name: phonesPerContact.keySet()){
        //Do whatever you want with the contact and its list of phones

        List<String> phones = phonesPerContact.get(name);
        Log.i("test", "Name: " + name + ", Numbers: " + phones.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Thx for taking a stab at it (+1), I'll have to see what implementation I'll choose in the end.